# Laravel Starter website working but Redirecting not working

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to follow a simple tutorial. I think I installed everything correctly and when I run the virtual machine, the laravel homepage shows up. I also added this in the web.php code:

```
Route::get('/home', function(){
    return "This is the home page";
});
```

If I followed the tutorial video then doing [website.com]/home , It will just print a string saying "This is the home page" But when I save and launch it, it comes up with a 404 error. I dont see what the problem is and I apologise for just being a beginner with this.

Comment: Do you clarify this line _But when I save and launch it_?

Comment: Your code is correct. The problem is somewhere else but I would need more data to help you (e.g. server logs).